# json_encode wraps result in extra symbols and new lines

Tags: php, json

I have a PHP script which serves JSON data.
Output code is basically this:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
```

It works fine on my home server, but on a web hosting it adds some symbols and new lines to response, like this:

```
2c13
[{
    "id":"34",
    "category_id":"9",
    "title":"\u0423\u0431\u0438\u0442\u0430\u044f \u0440\u0435\u0437\u0438\u043d\u0430",
    "max_quantity":"0","power":"10","price":"1000"
},
{
    "id":"35",
    "category_id":"9",
    "title":"\u0420\u0435\u0437\u0438\u043d\u0430 \u0441 \u0433\u0440\u044b\u0436\u0435\u0439",
    "max_quantity":"0",
    "power":"12",
    "price":"1000"
}, {
    "id":"36",
    "category_id":"9",
    "title":"\u041a\u043e\u043b\u0451\u0441\u0430 \u0441 \u043a\u0440\u0438\u0432\u044b\u043c \u0434\u0438\u0441\u043a\u043e\u043c",
    "max_quantity":"0",
    "power":"15",
    "price":"1000"
}, {
    "id":"80",
    "category_id":"9",
    "title":"\u041f\u043e\u0434\u0435\u0440\u0436\u0430\u043d\u043d\u044b\u0435 \u043a\u0430\u0442\u043a\u0438",
    "max_quantity":"0",
    "power":"18",
    "price":"1000"
}]
0
```

Second line is completely identical to response on my home server and is what the response should be.
`json_last_error()` returns 0.
I can't figure out why is this happening.
What can cause this problem?

Comment: I don't think `json_encode()` is at fault here. Are you sure you're not outputting anything after the call? If so, post the output of `var_dump($data);`.

Comment: Maybe the problem is in the `$data`. Try this to check what's really in there: `echo "<pre>"; print_r($data); echo "</pre>";`

Comment: Remove `echo json_encode($data)` and check the response again.

Comment: @xdazz without `echo json_encode($data)` response is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Check your array $data. It may have contains some extra value. Json_encode just only convert our php array into json array.